# All values from first column matching values in second column as well as not matching values from second column

Tags: mysql, sql

| userColumn | permissionColumn |
| --- | --- |
| user1 | permission1 |
| user1 | permission2 |
| user2 | permission1 |
| user3 | permission1 |
| user3 | permission3 |
| user4 | permission1 |

As cited in the subject line, I need to fetch all those users who have permissions **`'permission1'`** but at the same time, I have to make sure that it doesn't have the other permissions like **`'permission2'`** and **`'permission3'`**.

How can I achieve this with MySQL? Will it work with just a single query or do we need an inner join or nested query?

Desired Result:

| userColumn |
| --- |
| user2 |
| user4 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```sql
SELECT user
FROM table
GROUP BY user
HAVING NOT SUM(permission <> 'permission1');
```

`permission <> 'permission1'` returns 0 for 'permission1' and 1 otherwise.

SUM() by fact counts the amount of non-`'permission1'` values. We need the rows where there is no `'permission1'`, i.e. where this sum is zero.

NOT inverts SUM() result - i.e. converts zero to 1 and non-zero to 0. As a result we obtain only needed rows.

The query assumes that `permission` column cannot be NULL.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using conditional aggregation while grouping by `user` in order to check whether number of permissions of values `permission1` equals to the number of all rows per each user such as

```sql
SELECT user       
  FROM UserPermissions
 GROUP BY user
HAVING COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN permission = 'permission1' THEN 1 END)
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6018bddf1087f6760acfeb7db380ca10)</kbd>